# Is it possible to append data into a html element using DOM in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have looked for duplicate questions, however many refer to adding data to XML
please forgive me if I have missed something here but I need some help

so far I have this:

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Template</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/controlpanelAdmin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/controlpanelModerator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/css.css" />
</head>
<body>
<fieldset id="control_panel">
<legend>Control Panel</legend>
</fieldset>

<p id="content"> Content </p>

</body>
</html>
```

controlpanelAdmin.js

```
window.onload = function() {

var controlpanel = document.getElementById("control_panel");
var para = document.createElement("p");
var att = document.createAttribute("admin");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var txt = document.createTextNode("Admin Control Panel");



controlpanel.appendChild(para);
para.setAttribute("id", att);
para.appendChild(txt);
para.appendChild(br);
}
```

controlpanelModerator.js

```
window.onload = function() {

var controlpanel = document.getElementById("control_panel");
var para = document.createElement("p");
var att = document.createAttribute("mod");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var txt = document.createTextNode("Moderator Control Panel");



controlpanel.appendChild(para);
para.setAttribute("id", att);
para.appendChild(txt);
para.appendChild(br);
}
```

When the page loads, 'Admin Control Panel' is written into the fieldset tag
but is then replaced by: 'Moderator Control Panel'

I cannot for the life of me think how to append both lines (and maybe other data as well) into one element

Comment: window.onload is a single callback, which you are clobbering ... use `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... your code ...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the page loads, 'Admin Control Panel' is written into the fieldset tag but is then replaced by: 'Moderator Control Panel'

That can't happen. *Admin Control Panel* should never appear in the page.

1. `script/controlpanelAdmin.js` loads. It causes a value to be assigned to `window.onload`.
2. `script/controlpanelModerator.js` loads. It causes that value to be **overwritten** with a new one.
3. The page finishes loading
4. The load event fires
5. The function defined in `script/controlpanelModerator.js` is called

Don't assign values to `window.onload`. Use `addEventListener` instead.

```
addEventListener("load", function () { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked a treat. 
Back to school I go :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've got two onload functions competing. Can you merge them into one function?

Comment: they are seperated because I want some users that are moderators just to run code from: controlpanelModerator.js  and admins to run both
I just went the wrong way about loading them into DOM :-)